# Guidelines for mixing gases?

Tags: gas-laws

I want to create several mixtures of oxygen and nitrogen gas, such as 0% oxygen, 10% oxygen, 20% oxygen, 30% oxygen... 100% oxygen, but I know very little about working with gas cylinders and regulators. Is it as simple as connecting the two cylinders with a y-shaped hose and setting the flow rates to 10% oxygen and 90% nitrogen? Or will I need a more complicated setup?

This is for dissolving the gas mixture in water so I can test methods for determining dissolved oxygen levels. I'm not filling SCUBA tanks or anything dangerous, but I would still like the mixtures to be fairly accurate so I can get good data.

Comment: I think you should speak with your compressed gas vendor to get an understanding of what is required once you have your experiment properly defined. Working with pure oxygen and nitrogen is dangerous and shouldn't be done without proper safety guidance.

Comment: @J.Ari - I'd agree that working with pure oxygen can be dangerous because of the flammability hazard. The only problem that I can think of for pure nitrogen would be asphyxiation which seems unlikely.

Comment: @MaxW Since the OP indicated a lack of experience working with compressed gas sources and technologies, it's my opinion that no hazard (e.g. over pressure, flammability, asphyxiation, leakage) should be considered unlikely until proper system design and construction expertise is consulted and a documented hazard review is completed.

Comment: @J.Ari - You are correct. I handled gas cylinders for so many years that I forgot about even basic considerations like strapping the cylinder. Breaking the stem off would of course turn the cylinder into a missile.